# How to call function from shell script from ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, popen3

How to call function in shell script from ruby (preferably using open3)

```
#!/bin/sh
# A simple script with a function...

function add()
{
  echo "1"
}
```

Ruby Script that does not work--

```
#!/apollo/bin/env ruby
# -*- ruby -*-   
require 'open3'
Open3.capture3('.\something.sh', 'add')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you should have a [valid bash function declaration](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php).

Assuming `something.sh` was corrected to:

```
#!/bin/sh
# A simple script with a function...

bar () {
  echo "1"
}
```

You have to load it’s content into current shell *and* execute a function *in it*:

```
Open3.capture3(". ./something.sh && bar")
#⇒ ["1\n", "", #<Process::Status: pid 17113 exit 0>]
```

Answer (score 0):

For interest of others posting the answer. Basically, I end up doing work around like -

```
#!/apollo/bin/env ruby
# -*- ruby -*-   
require 'open3'

Open3.capture3(
    'bash',
    '-c',
    "source something.sh && add")
```

Basically Open3 (due to Ruby) fires every commands in different sessions and hence source of an script and method call should be done in single call.

Comment: How is it different from what I proposed? `.` is a shorthand for `source` in `bash`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thats why i accepted your answer and voted up but wanted to put my version because it using bash -c and parameterized parameter in capture3.